# ZXingObjC error in React Native, stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, react-native

The build fails because of this error

> CompileC
> /var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/printapp3-bdgcuaoitzijpkgdxzcqqilqaxei/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ZXingObjC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZXingObjC-iOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ZXResultParser.o
> /Users/master/Desktop/biolime/cfprint/node_modules/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/ios/ZXingObjC-3.2.2/ZXingObjC/client/result/ZXResultParser.m
> normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (in target 'ZXingObjC-iOS' from project 'ZXingObjC') (1 failure)

In Xcode as you see in screenshot below show the error with this line of code

[image: Screen Shot 2022-04-21 at 3 53 18 AM (2)]

> /Users/app/node_modules/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/ios/ZXingObjC-3.2.2/ZXingObjC/client/result/ZXResultParser.m:252:20:
> 'stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated: first
> deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -stringByRemovingPercentEncoding instead,
> which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding.

**Can please someone assist me with the objective-c part**

```
+ (NSString *)urlDecode:(NSString *)encoded {
  NSString *result = [encoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
  result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  return result;
}
```

When I replace

```
result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

with

```
result = [result stringByRemovingPercentEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I face this error

> /Users/app/node_modules/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/ios/ZXingObjC-3.2.2/ZXingObjC/client/result/ZXResultParser.m:252:20:
> No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector
> 'stringByRemovingPercentEncoding:'

Answer (score 0):

```
stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
```

does not take any parameters. Just call it on the string you want to affect and it will return an NSString * with the result:

```
result = [result stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
```

Comment: It works but the variable passed along throws an error in a different file: `Expression does not compute the number of elements in this array; element type is 'const unichar' (aka 'const unsigned short'), not 'char'`